# Collision issue on Python snake game

Tags: python

Have an issue with a game of snake in Python im making where my collision check isnt working. I have written a function to check a collision between the snake and the food itself. When it collides it doesnt do anything, i have written it to undraw if it collides using the function, i also put in a print function to see if the function was working if i was using it and saw no print.

```
def collide(block1,block2):
     if math.sqrt(((block2.getCenterX() - block1.getCenterX()) **2)+ ((block2.getCenterY() - block1.getCenterY())**2)) < BLOCK_SIZE:
         print("true")
         return True
     else:
         return False
 ------------------------------------------------------- not part of functiom
    if collide(theSnake[0],food) == True:
    food.undraw()
    foodX = random.randint(BLOCK_SIZE, WIN_WIDTH-BLOCK_SIZE)
    foodY = random.randint(BLOCK_SIZE, WIN_HEIGHT-BLOCK_SIZE)
    food.draw()
    theSnake.append(block)

    else:
    foodX = foodX
    foodY = foodY
```

Comment: Well, what are the values? Why do they never satisfy the condition? Hint: [consult the distance equation definition](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm). Also, don't use distance for snake (when/if grid-based) collisions.

Comment: Do you ever get an error?

Comment: Your problem may be that you are not squaring the differences between the x and y values, rather multiplying by two. Try changing the *2 to **2.

Comment: The values are both the X and Y coords in both the food and the snake

Comment: Changed it to **2 still no difference. No i dont get an error at all

Comment: Hmm, that's the only error I can see with your collide function. Are you sure you changed both `*2`s?

Comment: I can add my whole code in if there is an errorsomewhere

Comment: Are the blocks occupying discrete tiles? If so you could just compare the values of each block to see if they are equal?

Comment: No they are not. I was given this half done, they work off of a block size and the size of the screen

Comment: Is the food and snake made of circles? If not, then you might need to modify your distance formula...

Comment: No, its made of 2 squares when moving.

Comment: Why not use `math.hypot` to calculate the distance? Less places for bugs

Comment: Requirement for the program for sqrt

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you modify your collide function to provide more information. eg.

```
def collide(block1,block2):
    dx = block2.getCenterX() - block1.getCenterX()
    dy = block2.getCenterY() - block1.getCenterY()
    dist = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) # equivalent to math.hypot(dx, dy)
    if dist < BLOCK_SIZE:
        print("true")
        return True
    else:
        print("false", dx, dy, dist)
        return False
```